# Equivalent function for file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to parse some information out of a html page.
Currently I solve the problem like this:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");    
$this->pageSource = file_get_contents ($this->page);
header("Content-type: text/html");
```

`$this->page` is the url of the website.
This works fine on XAMPP, but when I upload my script on my webserver, I get the following error message:

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

So obviously I am not allowed to execute that function on my webserver.

So is there an equivalent function to solve my problem?

Comment: You can use the function, but not with URLs, only with local files, that's what the error message tells you.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` could be used to open URLs, but it could not handle timeouts or work behind a proxy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually the function `file_get_contents` is not disabled,
but `allow_url_fopen` is disabled

you can replace it with `curl`

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$this->pageSource = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

However, if you server block outgoing traffic, `curl` does not help too

Comment: Could I use CUrl to get the content and then manipulate it using Simple Html Dom Parser ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`curl()`](http://si.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

Answer (score 2):

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is the usual standard solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `curl` and why do you need to change the header to plain text to retrieve data? This is not necessary if you are retrieving data.

Answer (score 0):

if you have curl, use it it is great for this.

```
            $urlx = 'http://yoururl';

            $data="from=$from&to=$to&body=".urlencode($body)."&url=$url";   
//set post parameters
            $process = curl_init($urlx); 
//init curl connection
            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 

            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 

            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

            curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

            curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);

            $resp = curl_exec($process); 
//your content
            curl_close($process);
```