# Youtube video title not available?

Tags: php, mysql, youtube

This is how I try to get the Title of a youtube video.

```
        $url=$_POST['video'];
        $video=explode("=", $url);
        $code = explode("&",$video[1]);
        $video_feed = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=".$video[1]."&max-results=1&fields=entry(title)&prettyprint=true");
        $video_obj = simplexml_load_string($video_feed);
        $video_str = $video_obj->entry->title;
        echo $video_str;
        echo $code[0];          
        $sql="INSERT INTO youtube (y_vid,y_name)
        VALUES('".$code[0]."','".mysql_real_escape_string($video_str)."')";
        mysql_query($sql);
```

It works on localhost but on other server it doesn't save the title. Please help me.

Comment: Do some basic error checking and debugging first. What fails at which point?

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /wwwroot/admin/video-uj.php on line 29 Warning: file_get_contents(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=vw61gCe2oqI&max-results=1&fields=entry(title)&prettyprint=true): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /wwwroot/admin/video-uj.php on line 29 vw61gCe2oqINULL

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on a random video URL and it worked fine. Only thing that may cause the problem is that you are exploding the first string on `=`, video URL can contain multiple `=`'s so I would change it to:

```
$video=explode("v=", $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the
>   server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

This means that you have disabled allow_url_fopen in your php.ini. You need to turn it on by changing your php.ini, or you can use:

> ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);

Alternatively, you can use `curl` instead of `file_get_contents()`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4656156/2104225). It worked for me too.

Comment: How can I turn it on? I think I have no access to the php.ini

Comment: If you dont have permissions and `ini_set()` is not working either, try to use `curl`. Check my answer edit.

Comment: Could you help me to put this in my code? I've never used it and tomorrow morning I have to show a working code to my teacher :/

Comment: You just replace `file_get_contents()` in your solution with conent in that answer, where you replace `$this->page` with `"http://gdata.youtube.com/..."` and `$this->pageSource` with `$video_feed`.