# Laravel failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ini

I had a look around and most of the answers weren't for shared hosting which happens to be my case.

I've done `chmod` on `storage` and `bootstrap/cache/` to `775`. I also have a `storage/framework/views` directory, I have also tried deleting `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

N.B The script worked well on my former shared hosting plans and only the page with a `file_get_contents` seems to be the issue.

The file in question is `ErrorException` in `PostController.php line 17`: where I'm using a `file_get_contents` call.

Comment: Which file is being denied permission?  Normally this error includes the file path.

Comment: Its a here at ErrorException in PostController.php line 17:

Comment: I would imagine that `file_get_contents` is disabled with your shared hosting provider. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656102/equivalent-function-for-file-get-contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent function for file\_get\_contents()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656102/equivalent-function-for-file-get-contents)

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal add your `PostController` code where you are getting error

Comment: show your `PostController`

Answer (score 5):

On CentOS 7 + Apache:

```
cd /var/www/laravelfolder
sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/laravelfolder
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/laravelfolder -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/laravelfolder/storage -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/laravelfolder/bootstrap/cache -R
```

From: https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/

Comment: This was a good solution for me trying to track down a "Permission denied" for vendor/autoload.php when those files were already on my system with what I thought were correct permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Try running

`php artisan config:cache`

and then

`php artisan env`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have set wrong permissions. Give 777 permissions instead of 775 to bootstrap\cache and storage directory. Please have a look [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation#configuration)